# Less preprocessor for imports

Tags: plugins, less

I am in need of writing a preprocessor plugin for less files. I would like to have the imports of a top level less file be commented out and then their respective contents inserted into the top level file.

I have less files which import large numbers of other less files. If the top level less file already has its imports included, this dramatically reduces the number of requests for imported less files and seems to be a better approach for performance and also for running in IE where we are experiencing crashes.

Has anyone written such a plugin? Any ideas on how this might be accomplished are welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you mean something different to the @import that happens in Les?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you just need to add "import options" to your LESS imports. You can see all the options here: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options

Also, by default, each LESS file is only loaded once.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I caught your point precisely. Here are a few examples of Less's preprocessing plugins which provide global `@import` directives:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-plugin-est
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-plugin-lesshat
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-plugin-bootstrap

Actually I added preprocessing plugin for Less just for this purpose.